# Converting object to an encodable object failed: Instance of 'ThemeData'

Tags: list, flutter, themes, sharedpreferences

In my app I would like to save a list that contains `ThemeData`, a bool and a string variable. I am trying to map the class to save it into `Shared Preferences`, but I get this error when I am encoding the list:

`Converting object to an encodable object failed: Instance of 'ThemeData'`

Here is the CustomThemeModel class:

```
class CustomThemeModel {

  ThemeData myThemeData = new ThemeData();
  String themeName;
  bool readOnly = false;

  CustomThemeModel({
    required this.myThemeData,
    required this.themeName,
    required this.readOnly,
  });

  CustomThemeModel.fromMap(Map map) :
        this.myThemeData = map['myThemeData'],
        this.themeName = map['themeName'],
        this.readOnly = map['readOnly'];

  Map toMap(){
    return{
      'myThemeData': this.myThemeData,
      'themeName': this.themeName,
      'readOnly': this.readOnly,
    };  
  }
}
```

And the void method that will save the list:

```
void saveData(){
    List<String> spList = myThemes.map((e) => json.encode(e.toMap())).toList();
    print(spList);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to cast your `fromMap` constructor like so.

```
  CustomThemeModel.fromMap(Map map) :
        this.myThemeData = map['myThemeData'] as ThemeData,
        this.themeName = map['themeName'] as String,
        this.readOnly = map['readOnly'] as bool;
```

I'll elaborate a bit more in my main answer. What's the usecase here that you must convert the `CustomThemeModel`s that you have to a map? To keep things simple and to help you troubleshoot your issue, I'd suggest splitting things up in a logical way first.

I assume you want to have a list of custom themes, so make a list that is just that. Below a quick mock up that allows you to add to the list in a basic way and construct your list of custom themes.

```
final List<CustomThemeModel> customThemes = [];
void addToCustomThemes(CustomThemeModel model) {
  customThemes.add(model);
}

...

InkWell(
  onTap: () {
    addToCustomThemes(CustomThemeModel(
        myThemeData: ThemeData(),
        themeName: 'customThemeName1',
        readOnly: false,
      ),
    );
  }
)
```

You can find a theme model in this list quite easily.

```
for (final theme in customThemes) {
  return theme.where(theme.themeName == 'my theme name');
}
```

Edit2: For your particular usecase, I would do something like this. Note that the code was typed in the text editor here exclusively, so it might not run without needing a few small tweaks, but the idea is there.

```
final List<CustomThemeModel> customThemeModels = [
  CustomThemeModel(
    myThemeData: ThemeData(),
    themeName: 'My name',
    readOnly: true,
  ),
  // Add all CustomThemeModels here
];
// Create the list of ThemeData from your custom list
final List<ThemeData> themeData = customThemeModels.map((themeModel) {
  return themeModel.myThemeData;
}).toList();
```

Now, the order of both your lists is the same, thus allowing you to find the index of the theme that you want to use by providing the name that you gave.

```
int getIndex(nameToCheck String) {
  return customThemeModels.indexWhere((theme) => theme.themeName == nameToCheck);
}
```

And you can then use this index to provide the correct index to your package.

Comment: It worked, but now if I want to use the saved data with fromMap I get an error like this:
 Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'ThemeData' in type cast

Comment: There's something not quite right with your `saveData` method. You convert your themes into a List of strings, but you treat the String as a json object. Thus converting what was a key-value pair of String: ThemeData to just raw String (or a key-value of String: String). Why not make your list of custom themes just a List<CustomThemeModel>, pushing each new one you make to the end of the list?

Comment: @KrekZsole Check out my edit of the original post, maybe that helps you getting things back to basics. Using maps and converting to json seems quite unnecessary here.

Comment: My whole idea is that I have a CustomThemeList class where I can provide the ThemeData, the name of the theme and if its readonly or not. From this class I give the ThemeData to a List<ThemeData> because the plugin that I am using needs a ThemeData list to get the Themes (the plugin is stacked_themes). So basically I only use the CustomThemeData class to display the Theme name, and use the ThemeData list to set the Theme. This whole concept works. until I would like to save them.

Comment: I think you should look for a solution where you ditch the JSON / map  solution that you've had (it overcomplicates the problem by a ton), and just store two lists in your global state. One containing the ThemeData for your package, and one containing the CustomThemeModel to help you pick the right one.